# Google Cloud Vision returns incorrect end-time for MP4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, object-detection, mp4, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I encountered an issue with Cloud Vision when using object detection on MP4 videos.

When processing MP4 videos that were recorded on iPhone (Safari) with **~5 fps**, the endTimeOffset is incorrectly computed. In addition, the time-offset of detected objects is incorrect as well.

For example, processing a 4.5 seconds MP4 with a frame-rate of 5fps yields the following result:

```
 {
  "annotationResults": [
    {
      "segment": {
        "endTimeOffset": "0.834166s",
        "startTimeOffset": "0s"
      },
      "inputUri": "/obfuscated_path/c9bb312c-77ef-4fc2-a577-698e10797316.mp4",
      "frameLabelAnnotations": [
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0643t",
            "description": "personal computer",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.5484067,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01m3v",
              "description": "computer",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/01y9k5",
            "description": "desk",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.73044074,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/0c_jw",
              "description": "furniture",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/01c648",
            "description": "laptop",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.44585767,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01m3v",
              "description": "computer",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0hgr6",
            "description": "denim",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.5713141,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01l0y0",
              "description": "material",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0521dbh",
            "description": "texture",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.7152492,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/04t7l",
            "description": "metal",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.41139424,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01l0y0",
              "description": "material",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0bs7_0t",
            "description": "electronic device",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.8224686,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/07c1v",
              "description": "technology",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/03rb85",
            "description": "space bar",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.47278294,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/05148p4",
              "description": "keyboard",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/01jwgf",
            "description": "product",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.41716594,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0mwc",
            "description": "angle",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.549278,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/01m2v",
            "description": "computer keyboard",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.72498393,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01m3v",
              "description": "computer",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0hwky",
            "description": "pattern",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.4402157,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/02cwm",
              "description": "design",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/03gq5hm",
            "description": "font",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.40755123,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01mf0",
              "description": "software",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/07c1v",
            "description": "technology",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.75586826,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/01s0vc",
            "description": "zipper",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.5386912,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0dnr7",
            "description": "textile",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.7576094,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01l0y0",
              "description": "material",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/025rhd",
            "description": "pocket",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.40245184,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/09j2d",
              "description": "clothing",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/021sj1",
            "description": "office",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.48269805,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/0cgh4",
              "description": "building",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/03y18t",
            "description": "product design",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.65990233,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01g317",
              "description": "person",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/01l0y0",
            "description": "material",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.6393157,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0c_jw",
            "description": "furniture",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.7550465,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/036jvk",
            "description": "stock photography",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.42999625,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/05wkw",
              "description": "photography",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/04bcr3",
            "description": "table",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.41750312,
              "timeOffset": "1s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/0c_jw",
              "description": "furniture",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/083vt",
            "description": "wood",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.6359058,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "entity": {
            "entityId": "/m/0fkqd",
            "description": "linen",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "frames": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.41833103,
              "timeOffset": "0s"
            }
          ],
          "categoryEntities": [
            {
              "entityId": "/m/01l0y0",
              "description": "material",
              "languageCode": "en-US"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The exact properties of the MP4 file are:
Resolution: 1280x720; Frame-rate: 5.236; Length: 4.5s;

This is clearly incorrect. The issue reproduces quite easily with a long MP4 video (more than 15 seconds)

It needs to be said that processing WEBM videos with similar resolution and FPS returns the results correctly, meaning the end time and time offsets are correct for WEBM.

Is this a known issue for MP4?
Is there a way to resolve this?

Thanks.

---

Adding a snippet of the Java code that is used for execution:

```
// --snip
// Set the label detection mode
LabelDetectionConfig config =
    LabelDetectionConfig.newBuilder()
        .setLabelDetectionMode(LabelDetectionMode.FRAME_MODE)
        .build();

// Set the video context with the above configuration
VideoContext context = VideoContext.newBuilder().setLabelDetectionConfig(config).build();

AnnotateVideoRequest request =
    AnnotateVideoRequest.newBuilder()
        // see reference at
        // https://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/videointelligence/v1beta2/AnnotateVideoRequest.Builder.html#setInputUri-java.lang.String-
        .setInputUri(videoObj.getUri())
        .addFeatures(Feature.LABEL_DETECTION)
        .setVideoContext(context)
        .build();

// -- snip

VideoIntelligenceServiceClient client = VideoIntelligenceServiceClient.create();

client.annotateVideoAsync(request);
```

Comment: Hi @SD, Which programming language library are you using? Is it possible to share the documentation you are following?

Comment: @kiranmathew I am using the Java SDK (artifact `google-cloud-video-intelligence` version 2.2.3). I'll try to add a snippet of how I'm executing the client. Once again, when analyzing a WEBM format everything works as expected.

Comment: @kiranmathew I added the code snippet.
I suspect, though cannot confirm, that service attempts to calculate the length of the video (or the time offset of the frame) by calculating the number of frames that it has processed and assumes that there are ~24 or ~26 FPS. For example, a 4.2 seconds video at 5.2 FPS would result in ~22 frames - if the service assumes 26 FPS then it would calculate the entire length as 23/26= ~0.84sec.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: Thanks @kiranmathew . 
I created the following issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271896083